# How to access DOM with angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Umbraco (cms) and Angular, I need to access a DOM property of umbraco ... Currently the solution is using jQuery for it, the idea is to remove all jQuery dependencies.
Do you know a good wait to access it? ViewChild is not working since I am trying to access a property and not a component

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by a property? You can access Elements via Angular's ViewChild. Have a look at this simple question and its answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013071/angular-2-view-child-element-ref-selecting-same-element-twice

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with Angular.

We can directly access the element by using ElementRef provided by @angular/core.

If you manipulate it by using a directive, most are likely to use `nativeElement` directly like this.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor (private el: ElementRef){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
  }
}
```

It will change the color of the element.